# Error 08001 while connecting to SQL Server by using PHP

Tags: php, sql, sqlsrv

Here is my problem, I have my connection handles like this:

```
$dbSrvName = 'servername';
    $dbName = 'database';
    $dbUser = 'user';
    $dbPass = 'password';

    $dbInfo = array(
        'Database' => $dbName,
        'UID' => $dbUser,
        'PWD' => $dbPass            
    );

    $this->dbConn = sqlsrv_connect($dbSrvName, $dbInfo);
    if(!$this->dbConn)
    {
        die(print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true), 1);
    }
```

When I trigger output from sqlsrv_errors() I get the following message:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 26
>   [code] => 26 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Client
>   unable to establish connection because an error was encountered during
>   handshakes before login. Common causes include client attempting to
>   connect to an unsupported version of SQL Server, server too busy to
>   accept new connections or a resource limitation (memory or maximum
>   allowed connections) on the server. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL
>   Server Native Client 10.0]Client unable to establish connection
>   because an error was encountered during handshakes before login.
>   Common causes include client attempting to connect to an unsupported
>   version of SQL Server, server too busy to accept new connections or a
>   resource limitation (memory or maximum allowed connections) on the
>   server. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 10054
>   [code] => 10054 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]TCP
>   Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]TCP
>   Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host. ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 26
>   [code] => 26 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Client
>   unable to establish connection [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server
>   Native Client 10.0]Client unable to establish connection ) [3] =>
>   Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 10054 [code] => 10054
>   [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Client unable to
>   establish connection due to prelogin failure [message] =>
>   [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Client unable to establish
>   connection due to prelogin failure ) ) [2014-12-31 08:35:25]

SQLSRV USED:
    **php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll**

So I am afraid the version of SQL is not compatible with this version of sqlsrv. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance and Happy New Year!

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess you are trying to remotely connect to the sql server. You need to make sure that is actually possible with your sql server configuration.

Then you need to make sure that the user account you are trying to connect with has proper permissions

Then firewall needs to be opened as well on the server...

here is a short list of things to check.

[Can't Connect Remotely](http://michaelellerbeck.com/2010/03/31/cant-connect-remotely-to-sql-server-2008/)

Comment: Hi, I am sure the user have enough permissions to connect remotely to the server and also I know the server allows those kind of connections. So I think there is no issues with the server side (talking about ports blocking). So I already connected from other clients and applications to the same server, database and user account.

Comment: According to the docs, you dont need to pass in the Database...

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php

Comment: If you don't use SQL user and pass to connect, PHP will try to connect using Windows authentication.

Comment: Yeah it was the Database Attribute. it looks like you do that via the Server Name. ... IE: $serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress"; Where sqlexpress is the Database name.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it was a misunderstanding! The database that I was trying to connect to is Oracle. So the PHP library is not compatible.

Thanks anyway...